# Weka API on Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse, weka, smo

i want to classify string type dataset with test and training labeled.
i use this code in Eclipse java while i import Weka.jar file already

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import weka.classifiers.functions.SMO;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector;
import weka.core.Instances;

public class Classify {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //load data set for training//
        BufferedReader breader = null;
        breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/nfrtraining.arff"));
        Instances train = new Instances(breader);
        train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

        //test data set for testing//

        breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/nfrtesting1.arff"));
        Instances test = new Instances(breader);
        test.setClassIndex(test.numAttributes() - 1);

        // classifier applied 
        SMO svm = new SMO();
        svm.buildClassifier(train);
        System.out.println(svm.getCapabilities().toString());

        Instances labeled = new Instances(test);

        //for label instances
        for (int i = 0; i < test.numInstances(); i++) {
            double clsLabel = svm.classifyInstance(test.instance(i));
            labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
        }

        //save labeled data
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("c:/labelled.arrf"));
        writer.write(labeled.toString());
    }
}
```

when i run this code an error is displayed like:

```
at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1277)
at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1208)
at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1506)
at weka.classifiers.functions.SMO.buildClassifier(SMO.java:1330)
at Classify.main(Classify.java:30)
```

this error is in scr file i am unable to eid. please someone help to resolve this problem

Comment: my data set is in textual format

Comment: In the stack trace the first line with the type of the error/exception and the error message is missing. Could you please add this line to your question? A marker in code line 30 and a link to the `Weka.jar` would also be helpful.